# How to read a value from Jenkins job console and then pass it over to the Test results report?

Tags: maven, jenkins, report, jobs

My Maven-based jobs in Jenkins are triggered automatically on a pre-scheduled basis and are creating **certain orders with unique numbers** and writing them down into *job's build output console*.

Is there any way **to retrieve these order numbers from the job's build output console** and further **to insert them into a final Tests Results Aggregator html report** (every order number should be placed against its correspondent Jenkins job name)?

Thanks

Comment: About which kind of `certain orders with unique numbers` are we talking about?

Comment: Those are the purchasing orders to deliver a product to the end customer. Every purchasing order has its own unique number.  This is more relevant to what the code behind the job does. The main thing is that they need to be retrieved somehow from build output console and passed over into test results report.

Comment: Your tests should log those information instead of relying on the test cases itself from my point of view...

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a good idea. The optimal way would be to make your test write these to somewhere it's accessible. But if you really want to process the console out there are a few ways to do this.

Following is a groovy way of doing this.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
     stage("Echo") {
                steps{
                    echo "12345667"
                    echo "12345667"
                    echo "12345667"
            }
        }
        stage('Get console output') {
            steps{
              script {
                // Retrive the console output
                def consoleLog = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(env.JOB_NAME).getBuildByNumber(Integer.parseInt(env.BUILD_NUMBER)).logFile.text
                echo "$consoleLog"
               // Do string processing here
              }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        success {
            echo "Success"
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use the following URL to retrieve the console text.

Externally: `http://localhost:8080/job/JOBNAME/BUILDNUMBER/consoleText`

Within the same pipeline: `${BUILD_URL}/consoleText`

Comment: Thanks YCR,
So theoretically I can parse the log file created by the test itself - I think I can easily figure out how to do that as it is not that difficult using Groovy. However, the second part looks a bit unclear - how to pass over the read value into the Test Results Aggregator html report. Any ideas on the level of the concept?

Comment: Yes. So how are you Aggregating the results? Using a Jenkins plugin?

Comment: Right, I am using "Test Results Aggregator" plugin for Jenkins. It generates an html report into which I intend to insert retrieved order numbers in a separate column.

Comment: I cannot give a concrete answer without knowing the end to end scenario and which tools you use at each stage. But as far as I understand once the report is generated you will have to alter it again with some groovy scripts. This can be done after calling the https://github.com/jenkinsci/test-results-aggregator-plugin/blob/master/README_Pipeline.adoc. But you should seriously check the possibility of getting this generated through the test framework itself.